# My full node seems to be rejecting tor connections

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, tor

I'm running my full node with bitcoin core v0.18.1 with a mostly default configuration on debian 9.11. Port 8333 is forwarded through my router and I have 20+ node connections, so can safely assume others are able to connect, at least through ipv4. A friend was testing his tor node however, and received the following error when attempting to connect to my bitcoind's tor hidden service address: `Socks5() connect to XXXXXX.onion:8333 failed: connection refused`

When I run `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` I can see *.onion addresses in the list, so I presume others are able to connect through tor, is that correct? I'm using UFW and have 8333 open from all addresses, although tor connections are through localhost so UFW rules shouldn't matter. Why does my node reject the connection to my friend's node?

Here's my bitcoin.conf:

```
bind=0.0.0.0
onlynet=ipv4
txindex=1
listen=1
maxconnections=256
dbcache=400
upnp=0
discover=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my node had auto-banned localhost (127.0.0.1) at some point. As a result bitcoind was rejecting all incoming connections from the tor service, including my friend's attempts. I removed the ban and he is able to connect.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you removed the ban?

Comment: I use [Bitcoin Node Manager][1] as a front-end for my bitcoind instance. It has a section to remove a ban on a specific IP. Note that I *believe* the auto-bans generated by bitcoind expire in 24 hours, so you could just wait a day. It's likely also possible to remove a ban on the command line with bitcoin-cli, although I'm not sure exactly how.


  [1]: https://github.com/Mirobit/bitcoin-node-manager